# How can I create a new column that could tell me if specific columns have NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

[image: DataFrame]

Saying that I have a DataFrame with 6 Columns and I want to add a new colum that could give me a 1 when column 3 to 6 is NaN and a 0 when not all of them are `NaN`
like this

[image: NaN Column]

How Can I do that?
Or How could I remove those rows where all those columns are NaN except from the fisrt 2 columns?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, here's one way:

```
df['<New Col Name>'] = df.set_index(['Date', 'Name']).isna().all(1).astype(int)
```